# Beamer: shrink + allowframebreaks

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am trying to combine shrink and allowframebreaks in my references slides.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \bibliography{../mylib}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[shrink=50, allowframebreaks]{References}
    \bibliography{../mylib}
\end{frame}
```

Unfortunately, they do not seem to work well together. How can I increase the number of references per slide? I am just getting 3 per slide at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of shrink, you could reduce the font size.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
   \bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```